# Como hacer una macro para que un Boton de Excel genere una accion?

Tags: excel, vba

Como darle una funcion a ejecutar a un boton en excel, el boton de excel es un boton de lista desplegable, por lo tanto quiero que me ejecute una accion, la accion que quiero que me de es que me aparezca un cuadro a completar en el cual ya tengo la macro para ello, lo que no se es como hacerle para que cuando le de a una de las opciones de mi lista desplegable me aparezca el cuadro necesario.

Aqui iria el Codigo del boton de lista desplegable para que cuando seleccione una opcion me habilite el cuadro correspondiente.
+ Macro abajo para cuadro a aparecer.

```
Sub Listadesplegable1_AlCambiar()
'
'Section1 Macro
' aparece section 1
'

ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-72
Range("D2:I11").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=60
Range("D58").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste  
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
Range("D57").Select

End Sub
```

esta es la funcion del primer cuadro y asi sucesivamente lo hace con los cuadro que quiero que aparezcan

Comment: Tienes una lista desplegable, y quieres que si le das en la opción 1 te ejecute el macro 1, si elijes la opción 2 te ejecute el macro 2 y así sucesivamente?

Answer (score 2):

con click derecho en tu lista desplegable,
le das en Formato Control --> Control -->vincular celda

en este ejemplo lo voy a vincular a la celda A1, entonces cuando cambie tu lista cambiara el valor en esa celda.

ahora solo llamas a la macro adecuada cuando cambias tu lista

```
Sub Listadesplegable2_AlCambiar()
   Select Case Range("A1").Value
   Case 1
        Call macro1
   Case 2
        Call macro2
End Sub
```